# Dropzone.js show stored images

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, dropzone.js

I am using `dropzone.js` in my Laravel app to upload and show images on my platform. Storing works fine. I am saving them to database and locally in folder structure which has `full_size` folder for full images and `icon_size` for ones which are supposed to fit as a thumbnail (basically a smaller copy of the image).

The issue I'm facing is when I try to show images. This is my dropzone config file:

```
Dropzone.options.realDropzone = {
  previewsContainer: '#dropzonePreview',
  previewTemplate: document.querySelector('#preview-template').innerHTML,
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  dictRemoveFile: 'Remove',

  // The setting up of the dropzone
  init: function () {

    var myDropzone = this

    $.get('/image', function (data) {

      $.each(data.images, function (key, value) {

        var file = {name: value.original, size: value.size}
        myDropzone.options.addedfile.call(myDropzone, file)
        myDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(myDropzone, file, 'images/icon_size/' + value.server)
        myDropzone.emit('complete', file)
      })
    })

    this.on('removedfile', function (file) {

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'image/destroy',
        data: {id: file.name, _token: $('#csrf-token').val()},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
          var rep = JSON.parse(data)
        }
      })

    })
  },
  error: function (file, response) {
    if ($.type(response) === 'string')
      var message = response //dropzone sends it's own error messages in string
    else
      var message = response.message
    file.previewElement.classList.add('dz-error')
    _ref = file.previewElement.querySelectorAll('[data-dz-errormessage]')
    _results = []
    for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      node = _ref[_i]
      _results.push(node.textContent = message)
    }
    return _results
  },
  success: function (file, done) {
  }
}
```

Ajax call on `/image` works fine and returns instances of images which are in the database

[image]

But when each of images is supposed to be included in the view, it is erroring out

[image]

The issue I'm facing is that it is erroring out because I am under a `/project` route since these are images connected to a project. I don't know how to remove that part of the route so that I fetch the pictures directly from my `public` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone encounters same problem, I have solved it by defining explicitly URL for fetching:

```
myDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(myDropzone, file, "http://" + window.location.hostname + '/images/icon_size/' + value.server)
```

The `http://` part is mandatory, otherwise it just appends it to existing link.